# Adding tabs after pressing a button in java

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jtabbedpane

I am using java swing and I want to add 3 tabs after the user is choosing "New" from `JMenuBar`.

The tabs won't be there when the application is started. These will be shown only after choosing "New".

How can I Do it? Do I need to add these to the `actionListener` of "New"? How it can be added?

Comment: i was adding insertTab within the actionListener. but it was showing method not found.

Answer (score 4):

Since you tagged this question with `JTabbedPane`, I assume that is the component you are using. You can use the [`addTab`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html#addTab%28java.lang.String,%20java.awt.Component%29) or [`insertTab`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html#insertTab%28java.lang.String,%20javax.swing.Icon,%20java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.String,%20int%29) methods to add a tab.

If you want to do this in reaction of a button press, putting those calls in the `ActionListener` is indeed a valid solution.

Answer (score 1):

add an `ActionListener` to your `JButton` like this:

```
final JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
    JButton addButton = new JButton("new");
    addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        //will be called if the button gets clicked
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();//will be displayed in the Tab
            tabbedPane.add("title", panel);
            //.add() is the easier way for tabbedPane.insertTab(many arguments here)
            //add what ever you like(repeat three times)
        }
    });
```

Comment: +1 for making me look into the source of tabbedPane.add(..) - astonishingly, it really is overridden to delegate to addTab (for components != UIResource :-)

Comment: @kleopatra looking at the documentation would have been sufficient. Javadoc mentions 'Cover method for `insertTab`.'

Comment: @Robin - true, though I'm used to not fully rely on documentation, being a lazy doc writer myself :-) Plus it doesn't mention the UIResource stuff: not important for application code, but for framework code (one surprise less ...)

Comment: this is not working.. It is not showing any error. But after clicking the button the tabs are not created.. I have tried it in jdk... and for insertTab it is showing "can not find insertTab symbol".